# Питон не replace кириллицу в файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, кириллица, replace

Задача состоит в том чтобы стереть все русские буквы в файле(.txt).
Допустим на входе qweqweqweабв.
На выходе питон почему-то пишет в файл вот такое: qweqweqwe°±І. Думаю проблема состоит в кодировке. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Укажите `encoding='utf-8'` , когда открываете файл

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо большое!